# Why am I getting an array index out of bounds exception?

Tags: java, arrays

Basically, I have an assignment that requires me to find the mode of a given set of numbers.

> This is my Method:
>
> ```
>  public void findMode (){
>   /* The vector data is analyzed and transferred into a smaller vector
>     smallList (0..100).  For each occurrence of n in vector data,
>     smallList[n] is incremented +1.  function Largest is then called
>     to find the largest quantity in vector smallList.  The mode(s)
>     is/are printed out. */
>
>     int loop, largest;
>     int[] smallList = new int[101];    
>     for (int i = 0; i < myHowMany; i++)
>     {
>         smallList[myData[i]]++;
>     }
>     int max = 0;
>     for (int i = 0; i < smallList.length; i++)
>     {
>         if (max < smallList[i]) 
>         {
>             max = smallList[i];
>         }
>     }
> //Max is 26
>     int size = 0;
>     for (int i = 0; i < smallList.length; i++)
>     {
>         if (i == max) size++;
>     }
>
>     int[] modes = new int[size];
>     int modeIndex = 0;
>     for (int i = 0; i < smallList.length; i++)
>     {
>         if (smallList[i] == max) 
>         {
>             modes[modeIndex] = smallList[i];
>             System.out.println(modes[modeIndex]);
>             modeIndex++;
>         }
>     } Everything compiles fine, but when I run this method, I get an out of bounds array method. I have no idea WHY this happens so I
> ```
>
> need to know if the community can help me

. 
Solved!

Please tell me if I need more information!

edit: I forgot to mention that I get the error here:

```
modes[modeIndex] = smallList[i];
```

New Problem:
I fixed the problem from before, but now, I find that my max goes unto the array so that modes = 26(max)

Comment: Try and look at the stack trace it should print the index that causes the out of bounds exception

Comment: Does the compiler tell you which line is giving the IndexOutOfBoundsException?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't learned what a stack trace is yet!

Comment: Try stepping through it in the debugger, you'll learn a lot that way. Verify that values are what you expect them to be.

Comment: I posted the part where the compiler gives the error and I haven't learned to use  debugger yet!

Comment: I posted the part where the compiler gives the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is in this line

```
if (i == max) size++;
```

It should be

```
if (smallList[i] == max) size++;
```

This is causing the size of `modes` to be wrong

Answer (score 1):

That should be clear enough: either modeIndex or i exceeds the array size. Since you're looping over smallList with smallList.length, I guess the error is in the modeIndex then. In this case, size (which is used to construct modes) isn't big enough.

Comment: Thank you! I basically found that I had to increase array [size] to [size+1]

Answer (score 0):

if (i == max) size++;
and then 
if (smallList[i] == max)

Please check your value for size.